# can't update a customer with put in erlang

Tags: post, erlang, put, riak

I'm trying to update a customer in my riak database and i get the error message below:
And I don't know what causing this error and what this error message means.

And the module I use is:

```
allowed_methods(Request, State) ->
    {['PUT'], Request, State}.

content_types_accepted(Request, State) ->
    {[{"application/json",to_json}], Request, State}.
```

---

The error

> webmachine error: path="/customer/cus/update" {error, {error,undef, [{customer_update,to_json, [{wm_reqdata,'PUT',http,
>   {1,1}, "127.0.0.1", {wm_reqstate,#Port<0.6513>, {dict,4,16,16,8,80,48,
>   {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}, {{[],[],[],
>   [[mediaparams,{"charset","UTF-8"}]], [],
>   [[resource_module|customer_update],
>   ['content-type',116,101,120,116,47,104,116,109, 108]], [],
>   [['content-encoding',105,100,101,110,116,105,116, 121]],
>   [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},
>   undefined,"127.0.0.1",'REQDATA',undefined,undefined,
>   {wm_log_data,undefined, {1322,989559,450145}, 'PUT', {6,
>   {"content-length", {'Content-Length',"121"},
>   {"connection",{'Connection',"Keep-Alive"},nil,nil}, {"content-type",
>   {'Content-Type', "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}, nil, {"host",
>   {'Host',"localhost:8000"},
>   {"expect",{"Expect","100-Continue"},nil,nil}, {"user-agent",
>   {'User-Agent', "Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)"}, nil,nil}}}}},
>   "127.0.0.1","/updatecustomer", {1,1},
>   404,0,undefined,undefined,undefined}},
>   [],"/customer/cus/update","//customer/cus/update",
>   {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
>   {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
>   {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},
>   [],".",500,1073741824,67108864,[],[], {6, {"content-length",
>   {'Content-Length',"121"},
>   {"connection",{'Connection',"Keep-Alive"},nil,nil}, {"content-type",
>   {'Content-Type',"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}, nil, {"host",
>   {'Host',"localhost:8000"},
>   {"expect",{"Expect","100-Continue"},nil,nil}, {"user-agent",
>   {'User-Agent',"Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)"}, nil,nil}}}}},
>   not_fetched_yet,false,
>   {1,{"content-type",{"Content-Type","text/html"},nil,nil}}, <<>>,
>   ["localhost"], 8000,[]}, undefined]},
>   {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3}, {webmachine_resource,do,3},
>   {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1},
>   {webmachine_decision_core,accept_helper,0},
>   {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1},
>   {webmachine_decision_core,handle_request,2},
>   {webmachine_mochiweb,loop,1}]}}

Answer (score 4):

You should define to_json/2 function.

For example:

```
to_json(RD, Result) ->
    {mochijson:encode(Result), RD, Result}.
```

Comment: I'm defining to_json in another module.

Comment: +1. And read some docs about webmachine, i think it will help further

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I lack the reputation to comment on the answer by Ilya.

**TLDR**: prefix `to_json` with the name of the module where you defined it

Longer answer:

> I'm defining to_json in another module

Looking at your `content_types_accepted/2` call, you aren't specifying which module `to_json` resides in, hence the `undef` error. Erlang function calls are always MFA -> module:function(arguments), you can only omit the module if the function is in the same module.

See also the [documentation on Erlang packages](http://www.erlang.se/publications/packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding this error is the part:

`{error, {error,undef, [{customer_update,to_json, ...`

Which reports an `undef` error. Errors of these kinds are described at:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#id81244

And you can see that `undef` means we have an undefined function. The error is due to a call `customer_update:to_json(..)` which then did not exist. That is the problem you have here.